# SQL Server, how to order by full string while only showing part of it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, sql-order-by

I have data that looks like this:

```
  Column_1
  '(A) Top Sort'
  '(B) Second Sort'
  '(C) Third custom Sort'
```

The letters were added to allow customer sorting.  I have many more than just three letters but I'll spare the full set for the example.

I'm doing this to show only the text:

```
  Select
  right(Column_1, len(column_1) -4) as 'Column_1'
  from Table_1
  order by Column_1 ASC
```

But the results are order by the right(Column_1, len(column_1) -4), and not the full field:

```
  Column_1
  Second Sort
  Third Custom Sort
  Top Sort
```

I am going crazy.  I want to sort it by something not shown in the query.  Not sure how to do this.  How can I sort this by the full string and only show part of the string?

EDIT - This is the top part of a union all statement.  There is only one other part and it will always be last (letter Z)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just include the table alias in the `order by`:

```
Select right(Column_1, len(column_1) -4) as Column_1
from Table_1
order by table_1.Column_1 ASC;
```

The problem is that `Column_1` by itself can refer either to the alias defined in the `SELECT` or to a column in a table.  Your SQL engine is resolving it to the alias.

Another solution is to just give the column a different alias, so there is no naming conflict:

```
Select right(Column_1, len(column_1) -4) as new_Column_1
from Table_1
order by Column_1 ASC;
```

Because `Column_1` is not found in the `SELECT` list, the name will resolve to the column in the table.

You cannot do this with a `union all` statement.  For that, you need a subquery:

```
select . . ., right(Column_1, len(column_1) -4) as column_1
from ((select  . . ., column_1  -- no SUBSTRING!
       from table1
      ) union all
      (select . . .
      )
     ) t
order by t.column_1;
```

Comment: What if it's the top part of a union all statement?

Comment: @user76595 . . . Then you would have a different question from the one being asked.  You would just make the column alias different from the name of a column in the table.

Comment: Ok my bad, edited the question.  Can you provide and example using a union all statement?

Comment: @user76595 . . . It is rude to edit a question after it has been answered.  That can invalidate answers, which draws downvotes.  This time, I'll edit the answer though.